# Flash AS2: An appropriate outline font is not available

Tags: macos, flash, actionscript, fonts, flash-cs5

I'm receiving the following error message when attempting to execute/compile Flash AS2 code within the development environment:

"Some characters could not be converted to outlines because an appropriate outline font is not available"

I haven't opened this movie in about a month, but it was created on this system. The fonts *are* indeed available, they're just not appearing within Flash.   And this is the very system which the original AS2 code was written in, and these are the original font files used when the movies were created.  Also, when I look at the Font pulldown in the text dialogs, the required fonts aren't appearing within Flash.  But they were appearing just a couple weeks ago.

I have verified the font files and they appear to be valid, working font files.

So why isn't Flash seeing them?  Is there some way to get Flash to re-scan the font directory (Does it not do that on progam-load anyway?).   Any help would be much appreciated.

Additional information: 
Flash CS5
AS2
OSX

Answer (score 0):

Well for anyone experiencing the same issue -- these are the steps I took to solve the problem, although it is not clear specifically which step did the trick in the end.

1)  Delete and Replace fonts causing the error.
2)  Reduce overall number of fonts (OSX had a large number of Arabic and Asian fonts which were not necessary).  I had nearly 1000 fonts -- which may have been causing memory issues.  Some of the fonts had file-sizes in the hundreds of megabytes.
3)  Restart OSX